# Compare 2 cells, then read a 3rd

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 workbooks. 1 used as a lookup, and 1 as raw data. There's CA-codes (employee codes) in both these workbooks. The CA-codes do not belong to the same departments however, and that is listed in the lookup workbook.

I need my macro to be able to

1. Check if CA-code exists in Rawdata workbook
2. Check the department
3. Continue if department is "BIB"

As you can see below, it currently only looks for the specific CA-codes, which means that i have to update that value in the lookup as well as the code.

I have not yet tried to get it to look for "BIB", as i have no clue how i would go about it.

**lookup data looks like this in the cells:**

CA-code | Org. level    | Name  | Department

ca00813 | 530040 | Employee employeeson |   BIB

BIB could be other departments.

Note that this is a sub being called mid-operation to validate the opening hours, IF the CA-code is a BIB Employee

```
Sub PS_Open() Dim LastRow4 As Long Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic Sheets("TempRaw").Activate LastRow4 = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Range("J2").Formula = "=Weekday(D2)"

Range("J2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("J2:J" & LastRow4)

Range("K2").FormulaLocal = "=INDEKS(Opslag_ugedage!$B$1:$B$7;SAMMENLIGN(J2;Opslag_ugedage!$A$1:$A$7;0))" Range("K2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("K2:K" & LastRow4)

Range("L2").FormulaLocal = "=TIME(D2)" Range("L2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("L2:L" & LastRow4)


 Dim rng As Range, rng2 As Range, x As Long  Dim Man As Integer, Tirs As Integer, Ons As Integer, Tors As Integer, Fre As Integer, Lør As Integer, Søn As Integer, IÅ As Integer
    Set rng = Range(Range("K2"), Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    Set rng2 = Range(Range("L2"), Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)) UÅ = 0 IÅ = 0 i = 0
    For x = rng.Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
        With rng.Cells(x)  **' IF it's a BIB employee If** rng.Cells(x).Offset(0, -6).Value = "ca00813" Or rng.Cells(x).Offset(0,
-6).Value = "ca00815" Or rng.Cells(x).Offset(0, -6).Value = "ca00818" _ Or rng.Cells(x).Offset(0, -6).Value = "ca6b101" Or rng.Cells(x).Offset(0, -6).Value = "ca6b60" Or rng.Cells(x).Offset(0,
-6).Value = "ca6b61" _ Or rng.Cells(x).Offset(0, -6).Value = "ca6b87" Or rng.Cells(x).Offset(0, -6).Value = "ca6b92" Or rng.Cells(x).Offset(0, -6).Value = "ca6b95" _ Or rng.Cells(x).Offset(0, -6).Value = "ca6b97" Or rng.Cells(x).Offset(0,
-6).Value = "ca6svs7" Or rng.Cells(x).Offset(0, -6).Value = "ca00816" _ Or rng.Cells(x).Offset(0, -6).Value = "ca01404" Or rng.Cells(x).Offset(0, -6).Value = "ca014041" Or rng.Cells(x).Offset(0, -6).Value = "ca6b63" _ Or rng.Cells(x).Offset(0, -6).Value = "ca00781" Or rng.Cells(x).Offset(0,
-6).Value = "ca00783" Or rng.Cells(x).Offset(0, -6).Value = "ca00785" _ Or rng.Cells(x).Offset(0, -6).Value = "ca00787" Or rng.Cells(x).Offset(0, -6).Value = "ca00789" Or rng.Cells(x).Offset(0,
-6).Value = "ca00790" _ Or rng.Cells(x).Offset(0, -6).Value = "ca00821" Or rng.Cells(x).Offset(0, -6).Value = "ca00928" Or rng.Cells(x).Offset(0, -6).Value = "ca00999" _ Or rng.Cells(x).Offset(0, -6).Value = "ca01083" Or rng.Cells(x).Offset(0,
-6).Value = "ca01267" Or rng.Cells(x).Offset(0, -6).Value = "ca01312" _ Or rng.Cells(x).Offset(0, -6).Value = "ca01313" Or rng.Cells(x).Offset(0, -6).Value = "ca01361" Or rng.Cells(x).Offset(0,
-6).Value = "ca01363" _ Or rng.Cells(x).Offset(0, -6).Value = "ca01364" Or rng.Cells(x).Offset(0, -6).Value = "ca00795" Or rng.Cells(x).Offset(0, -6).Value = "ca1f601" Then

    ' Så mål om det er indenfor åbningstiden i BSC og tæl antal UÅ (UdenforÅbningstid)


            If .Value = "Mandag" Then
                    If rng.Cells(x).Offset(0, 1) < 17 And rng.Cells(x).Offset(0, 1) >= 9 Then IÅ = IÅ + 1 Else UÅ = UÅ + 1
                    End If
            If .Value = "Tirsdag" Then
                    If rng.Cells(x).Offset(0, 1) < 13 And rng.Cells(x).Offset(0, 1) >= 9 Then IÅ = IÅ + 1 Else UÅ = UÅ + 1
                    End If
            If .Value = "Onsdag" Then
                    If rng.Cells(x).Offset(0, 1) < 13 And rng.Cells(x).Offset(0, 1) >= 9 Then IÅ = IÅ + 1 Else UÅ = UÅ + 1
                    End If
            If .Value = "Torsdag" Then
                    If rng.Cells(x).Offset(0, 1) < 17 And rng.Cells(x).Offset(0, 1) >= 9 Then IÅ = IÅ + 1 Else UÅ = UÅ + 1
                    End If
            If .Value = "Fredag" Then
                    If rng.Cells(x).Offset(0, 1) < 13 And rng.Cells(x).Offset(0, 1) >= 9 Then IÅ = IÅ + 1 Else UÅ = UÅ + 1
                    End If
            If .Value = "Lørdag" Or .Value = "Søndag" Then UÅ = UÅ + 1

        Else
        ' Ellers (Hvis det ikke er BIB medarbejder), så tæl IÅ (Indenfor Åbningstid)
            IÅ = IÅ + 1
            ' IÅ = IÅ + 1 Fre = Fre + 1 'And cell.Offset(0, 6).Value = "Mandag"
            'If Weekday = vbFriday Then Fre = Fre + 1 'And cell.Offset(0, 6).Value = "Mandag"

            End If
        End With
    i = i + 1
    Next x

Sheets("Ark1").Range("N13").Value = UÅ
    'MsgBox "Inden for åbningstid: " & IÅ & "   Udenfor åbningstid: " & UÅ


Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Slet TempRaw efter validering af tal ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TempRaw").Activate Application.DisplayAlerts = False ActiveSheet.Delete Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: you can add a function which checks whether the CA-code exists in the lookup value and if department is BIB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function check_dep(CA_code as variant,dep as varaint) as boolean
val1=CA_code
lr=workbook("Rawdata").sheets(1).range("A"& rows.count).end(xlup).row
for i=2 to lr
val2=workbook("Rawdata").sheets(1).cells(i,1).value
if val==val2 then
dep1=workbook("Rawdata").sheets(1).cells(i,4).value
if dep1=dep then
check_dep=True
else
check_dep=False
end if
end if
next i
return checK_dep
end function
```

you can use this function to check if the CA code belongs the required department you can use it in a if condition as

```
if check_dep("ca00813","BiB") then
'statements to be executed
end if
```

If a range of ca_codes needs to be checked use:

```
Dim cell as range
Dim ca_rng as range
Lr2= workbooks("Main workbook").Sheets(1). range("A"& rows.count).end(xlup).row
Set ca_rng= workbooks("Main workbook").Sheets(1). range("A2:A" & lr2)
For each cell in ca_rng
Ca_code= cell.vlaue
 IF Check_dep(ca_code,"BIB") then
 ' statements
 End if
 Next
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Does this mean i'd have to check it for all the ca-codes as well using if check_dep("ca00813","BiB") then ?

Comment: It checks for the ca_code you pass as argument in the argument and checks the department is the value you passed.....If you want to check for different ca_code in a different department you just have to pass those values as argument

Comment: If you have a range of ca_codes to be checked whether they are in BIB department...You can have a for loop for the cell pass those values one by one

Comment: Yeah, the thing is there's a lot of CA-codes, and i'm really only interested in the ones belonging to BIB.
The CA-codes should read from rawdata, check in lookup workbook, then if the department is BIB, do something. So i'm looking for a way to compare the two (i already got a macro for if it doesn't exist), then if it's department BIB continue

Comment: If you can upload a sample file, I ll check what i can do

Comment: Thank you very much. I had to remove a lot of data, as it's not something i can share publicly. The file is here; https://expirebox.com/download/a9e70479d468ff267a3c9ecd049bca8a.html .. It's only the "PasStat" modules in this case, and the listed code is under "PasStat_C_Open"

The other file, 0217 is the rawdata that the user is prompted to select

Comment: i cant find the department column in the raw data...can you tell which one is it?

Comment: there are sheets in the code that i cant find in the workbook...you have the value of ca_code and you want to lookup its department and do something if the value is BIB....this is what you want, Right?

Comment: Oh, right. The "Afd" in the other workbook is the Department column, in sheet "CA-koder". Sorry, did not change it to English :( And for the other question, that is right. I want it to find out if the CA-code in 0217 matches one in Sheet "CA-koder", and then IF it's BIB do the IÅ and UÅ thing

Comment: https://ufile.io/2e37d1    i have uploaded the file here...i might have changed the indeks and sammmelign functions to english change them back and check if it works

Comment: Thanks a lot Sivaprasath! 
It doesn't seem to count the UÅ now though?

Comment: After the function, which does return val1, "BIB", it just skips the whole "If .value = Monday" etc.

Comment: So the function must be returning false....Try msgbox the check_dep value in the function....To check if it's true

Comment: I stepped it step by step, and it is returning true. The val1 and "BIB"-parts are correct, and the check_dep_res is set to true before ending the function. When it ends, it just skips the weekday-IF's completely

Comment: Could it be related to the  "If check_dep(val1, "BIB") Then" not being " If check_dep(CA_code, "BIB") Then" ?? It jumps directly down to "Else"-part after the function is run

Comment: It's just passing the value....If you want inside the function print ca_code and select whether it's passed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138800/discussion-between-thiil-and-sivaprasath-v).